# How do I represent hierarchical data in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

Hi I'm totally new to backbone, and I'm trying to research the best way to represent the the data below.

- **Parent Updates** can have many children
- **Child Updates** are contained within an array embedded within the parent object.
- **Child Updates** have a parent_id set referencing the parent.
- **Child Updates** can't have any children, so the nesting is only one level deep.

Do I need to use backbone-relational or is that a bit overkill?

```
 {
    "id": "53c7c300-4b5c-467e-83d5-2023d1f54a2f",
    "challenge_member_id": "53c7c147-4e80-4ade-9e64-2015d1f54a2f",
    "foreign_key": "1",
    "model": null,
    "parent_id": null,
    "content": "<p>joe appleton is here today<p>",
    "created": "2014-07-17 14:35:12",
    "modified": "2014-07-17 14:35:12",
    "type": "update",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "53c7f452-f444-448d-9ce0-2519d1f54a2f",
            "challenge_member_id": "",
            "foreign_key": "",
            "model": "",
            "parent_id": "53c7c300-4b5c-467e-83d5-2023d1f54a2f",
            "content": "ggrrggrgrgrgrgrgrgr",
            "created": "2014-07-17 18:05:38",
            "modified": "2014-07-17 18:05:38",
            "type": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "53c7f45a-25d0-47c5-a287-2ebdd1f54a2f",
            "challenge_member_id": "",
            "foreign_key": "",
            "model": "",
            "parent_id": "53c7c300-4b5c-467e-83d5-2023d1f54a2f",
            "content": "ggrrggrgrgrgrgrgrgr",
            "created": "2014-07-17 18:05:46",
            "modified": "2014-07-17 18:05:46",
            "type": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "53c7f45e-ae9c-4cd1-91b3-2f8dd1f54a2f",
            "challenge_member_id": "",
            "foreign_key": "",
            "model": "",
            "parent_id": "53c7c300-4b5c-467e-83d5-2023d1f54a2f",
            "content": "ggrrggrgrgrgrgrgrgr",
            "created": "2014-07-17 18:05:50",
            "modified": "2014-07-17 18:05:50",
            "type": ""
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: what you use should depends on what you want to achieve with this model/collection. If your requirement is simple simple model containing a collection of children should be enough.

Comment: I've never used it personally, but you could check out [backbone-documentmodel](https://github.com/icereval/backbone-documentmodel).